# Word and normal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra, operator-algebras

i need to prove this result

Let $A$ a square complex matrix and let $\mathcal{W}(A,A^{*})$ be a word in $A$ and $A^{*}$ with lenght $m\geq 2$, and suppose that $\mathcal{W}(A,A^{*})$ contains $A^{2}$ or $(A^{*})^{2}$. Then

$\sigma(\mathcal{W}(A,A^{*}))=\sigma^{m}(A)$ if and only if $A$ is normal

(where $\sigma$ is singular values of a matrix)

Thanking you in advance !

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far? Are there any results that you've covered in your class or textbook that you expect to be useful for this problem? Are you able to prove the easy direction of this implication using the spectral theorem?

Comment: The statement is incorrect in its current form.  Note in particular that we will have
$$
\sigma(A^*A) = \sigma^2(A),
$$
regardless of whether $A$ is normal.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If $A$ is normal $\Longleftrightarrow$ the singular values of $A$ is $\{|\lambda_{i}\}$  where $\lambda$ eigenvalues of $A$ and we have $\sigma(\mathcal{W})= eigenvalues^{1/2} of (A^{*}A)^{m}$

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch of proof:**

With the spectral theorem, it is trivial that $A$ is normal implies $\sigma(\mathcal{W}(A,A^{*}))=\sigma^{m}(A)$.

For the converse, the Schur decomposition means that we may assume that $A$ is upper triangular without loss of generality.  Suppose moreover that the eigenvalues of $A$ are on the diagonal in decreasing order of magnitude.  We can write
$$
A = \pmatrix{\lambda & x^*\\0 & B}
$$
for some $x \in \Bbb C^{n-1}$ and eigenvalue $\lambda$.

**Claim:** If $\sigma_{\max}^m(\mathcal W) = \sigma_{\max}^m(A)$, then $x=0$.

**Proof:** Let $A$ be such that $\sigma_{\max}^m(\mathcal W) = \sigma_{\max}^m(A)$.  Suppose for the purpose of contradiction that $x \neq 0$. Let $\|A\| = \sigma_{\max}(A)$, which is to say that $\|\cdot\|$ dentoes the spectral norm. First, note that for any matrix $A$ and any two words $\mathcal W_1,\mathcal W_2$, we have
$$
\|\mathcal W_1 \mathcal W_2\| \leq \|\mathcal W_1\|\cdot \|\mathcal W_2\|.
$$
Use this to conclude that for any word $\mathcal W_k$ of length $m_k$, we have $\|\mathcal W_k\| \leq \|A\|^{m_k}$.  The word $\mathcal W$ under our consideration can be decomposed into
$$
\mathcal W = \mathcal W_1 A^2 \mathcal W_3.
$$
Now, show that $\|A^2\| < \|A\|^2$. Conclude that $\|\mathcal W\| \leq \|\mathcal W_1\|\cdot \|A^2\| \cdot \|\mathcal W_3\|< \|A\|^m$, contradicting our premise.

With the above claim established, we can inductively reach the desired conclusion.

---

**Claim:** If $x \neq 0$, then $\|A^2\| < \|A\|^2$.

**Ideas:** Note that
$$
A^2 = \pmatrix{\lambda^2 & x^*(\lambda I + B)\\ 0 & B^2},\\
A^2A^{*2} = \pmatrix{|\lambda|^4 + \|(\lambda I + B)x\|^2
& [\lambda^2 (\lambda I + B)x]^*\\
\lambda^2 (\lambda I + B)x & B^2 B^{*2}}\\
AA^* = \pmatrix{|\lambda|^2 + x^*x & x^*B\\
Bx & BB^*}\\
(AA^*)^2 = 
\pmatrix{(|\lambda|^2 + x^*x)^2 + \|Bx\|^2 
& (|\lambda|^2 + x^*x)x^*B + x^*BBB^*\\
\cdot & B[xx^* + B^*B]B^*}
$$

Comment: It seems that the last statement that we need to prove is not as easy to deal with as I had initially thought (hence the computations under "ideas"). Another potentially useful idea: note that the matrix $(AA^* - A^*A)^2$ is positive semidefinite and expand.